# ListView: How to get next index or item through loop iteration

Tags: c#, listview, winrt-xaml

I am new in development.I am developing a store application. I want to iterate my list so that every time I can get next item of list view.
I have a popup name edit popup and it has a button (add save). When user clicks any item in list view and opens popups to edit than upon saving if he clicks add save button than current item should be updated and the list view should select next value of the list view and popup data should also be replace with the next item data.
Here is my code till now:

```
if (addSaveBtnClick == true)
{
    PopupAddEditGarmentService.IsOpen = true;
    InvoiceGarmentServiceVM.getInvoiceGarmentServiceByInvoiceID(currentCustomerInvoice.InvoiceID);
    foreach (InvoiceGarmentServiceWork _invoiceGarmentService in InvoiceGarmentServiceVM.CollectionInvoiceGarmentServiceWork)// Lopp to iterate data from Collection
    {
        int _listCount = lvGarmentService.Items.Count;
        _listCount++;
        lvGarmentService.SelectedValue = _listCount;
    }
}
else
{
    PopupAddEditGarmentService.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your preference of whether you want to reference the viewmodel collection or the UI.
If you want to reference the UI, you can iterate through the items in the code behind by getting the SelectedIndex.

```
YourListView.SelectedIndex
```

Once you get the selected index you can run logic and set the next selected index.

```
int index = YourListView.SelectedIndex;
//set new index 
//don't forget to do boundary checks
YourListView.SelectedIndex += 1;
```

If you're interested in using the viewmodel collection to set the selected item, in the XAML you can set the

```
ListView.SelectedItem ="{Binding yourSelectedItemProperty}"
```

Then you can modify your selected item in the viewmodel and the view will update itself.